# Node.js events.js: 163 throw er; when executing Jest with flag --runInBand

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, travis-ci, jestjs

In our `package.json` we have added to the script test the [--runInBand flag](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/cli.html#runinband) in order to [speed up](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/161#issuecomment-260246866) travis tests. We're 5 people in our team and all of them have no problems but I'm having this error every time I run the script. This is what's looks like:

```
events.js:163
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: connect EHOSTDOWN 169.254.169.254:80 - Local (192.168.8.46:63717)
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1073:20)
    at internalConnect (net.js:889:16)
    at lookupAndConnect (net.js:977:5)
    at Socket.realConnect (net.js:945:5)
    at Agent.connect [as createConnection] (net.js:77:22)
    at Agent.createSocket (_http_agent.js:195:26)
    at Agent.addRequest (_http_agent.js:157:10)
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:212:16)
    at Object.request (http.js:26:10)
```

The script:

```
"test": "export APP_ENV=development && jest --no-cache --runInBand --forceExit",
```

If I remove this flag, I don't get this error. I don't know if it's related to Jest, Node, Travis, etc but I have been looking to resolve it for a long time and I have no more ideas.

My version are:

- Node: v7.10.0
- Jest: v19.0.2
- OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.4

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems to be related with node v7.10. I have downgraded to v7.9 and works fine.

Node team is [working on it](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/12841) and it will be the next v7.x release (which will probably be next week).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a problem with socket connection to 169.254.169.254:80

Can you checkout your development environment (MacOS) so that you can do socket connections?

I am not a Mac guru but EHOSTDOWN means that you can reach the host but cannot do the socket connection.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. How can I check that my mac can do socket connections? Thanks